# Scheduled path not running for some records

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I've got a pretty simple flow running on the contract object. There's two different scheduled paths set to run 180 days and 30 days before the End Date given on the contract record. The only start criteria is that the status field be set to activated. The two update records elements are each setting a single checkbox field to true.[image: flow diagram]

I've verified that all records which have had this issue meet the start criteria. I've run the records through the flow with debug and the scheduled paths have worked correctly for all tested records. There are no failed flow interviews pointing back to this flow. When I check Time-Based Workflow there are many pending scheduled path actions for this flow, so it appears that the flow itself is working.

Is anyone aware of what could be could be causing this? The only thing I could think of is that the multi-month delays between when the contracts are created/updated and when the flow should trigger is causing problems. I'm considering switching to a schedule triggered flow but am hoping to understand why this is happening before I commit to that.

Comment: Contracts that were activated before the Flow was deployed won't have any pending time-based-workflows. Could that be your issue?